# Scraping: Check if wiki a page is a person-page

Tags: web-scraping, wiki

I have been trying to scrape all the biography wiki pages for weeks. The problem is I can't find a way to distinguish a page concerning a person or something else.

For instance the following pages:

- view-source:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Einstein
- view-source:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider

look pretty similar regarding their HTML code. I am sure there must be a keyword allowing you to know if the page is related to a person.

Has anyone faced the same problem?
Thanks in advance =)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure there is a definite way to tell but you could build up a list of indicators that you think the page might be about a person and then match on these.

For example on the Albert Einstein page there is a section for "Born" and "Died" on the right pane. By having these present we can be pretty sure that this article is about a person (although if you look for died you'll probably only get dead people). These titles however aren't consistent and you would need to match against one or more of these to build up confidence that the article is indeed about a person. e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lionel_Messi doesn't contain the "Born" header but it does contain "Date of birth".

Alternatively to this you could do some natural language parsing to try and figure out if the main text on the page is talking about a person. Lots of mentions of "he" or "she", probably means the article is talking about a person.